# Emulate, debug BlackBerry mobile website

Tags: firefox, browser, web-development, blackberry, emulation

I'm developing a website that needs to be compatible for mobile phones (esp. BlackBerry). How can I debug it's CSS? I already installed the Default User Agent plug-in for Firefox problem is I just don't know how to add the BlackBerry agent.

Next problem is how can I properly emulate the mobile site? without the actually having the device.

I'm using Windows 7, Firefox + Firebug + Web Developer Toolbar. I know XHTML, CSS and WordPress.

Comment: I am also doing the same as you. I am using a virtual device, but there is nothing like firebug to help debug any css problems. All guess work right now. There IS an eclipse plugin, but it hasn't turned up much help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: Goto [User Agent String](http://www.useragentstring.com/) or [What's My User Agent](http://whatsmyuseragent.com/) from your BlackBerry Device. Note the user agent string and copy it somewhere.
Then use [User Agent Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/) with Firefox (4, preferably) and add the above string to it. Then visit your website, it should show the BlackBerry version. You may also want to use [WMLBrowser](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/wmlbrowser/) for WML browsing to emulate mobile devices.

Second: [The BlackBerry Forums](http://www.blackberryforums.com/developer-forum/253-useful-links-new-mobile-programmers-blackberry-sdk.html) might help. But true emulation of a BlackBerry device might not be possible due to an unsatisfactory RIM SDK.

Lastly, Mobile devices in general have very low amount of documentation as to their web browsing abilities... especially, the older phones. So you'll just have to try your best and [stick to the standards](http://www.w3.org/standards/) for maximum compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

According to this:

> http://www.blackberryforums.com/developer-forum/253-useful-links-new-mobile-programmers-blackberry-sdk.html

the RIM JDE has a built-in emulator that should do everything you want, emulate a Blackberry completely.  I have done this for Droid but not for the RIM platform so...It's worth a shot at least

Comment: note: the droid SDK emacs bundle has qemu devices that represent the droid almost perfectly...I can't imagine the RIM sdk does not have similar functionality